# IIS url wrerite when I try url with % sign say file or directory not exists?

Tags: iis

this is url I am trying http://localhost:9900/survey-items/take-survey/8Uawxo1bnCOp%2bj1FhSTt1g%3d%3d
I want it working properly without issues and this encoded urls are important and I want to preserve it

[image]

this is my web.config. all other urls working fine

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite >
          <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" >
                <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="(.*)" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" appendQueryString="true" url="/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: http.sys will never allow a bare ‘%’ character though because it is expressly forbidden in the RFC section 2.4.2 which says: Because the percent "%" character always has the reserved purpose of being the escape indicator, it must be escaped as "%25" in order to be used as data within a URI. Implementers should be careful not to escape or unescape the same string more than once, since unescaping an already unescaped string might lead to misinterpreting a percent data character as another escaped character, or vice versa in the case of escaping an already escaped string”

Comment: More details please refer to this [article](https://blogs.iis.net/nazim/use-of-special-characters-like-in-an-iis-url)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding following content related to security under system.webServer inside web.config

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```